# Executar threads simultâneas em java com parâmetros, método run

Tags: java, thread

Tenho um serviço hoje que preciso calcular seu tempo de execução com múltiplos acessos, para isso estou tentando executar threads simultâneas e que loguem esse tempo, o problema é que para o método run da classe Thread não posso passar parâmetros e no caso eu preciso destes parâmetros para execução do serviço. Como posso fazer isso? Estou no caminho certo? Segue código:

```
for(int x = 0; x<50 ; x++){
    new Thread() {
       long tempInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
       @Override
        public void run(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, String sequence,
                CommandMapping commMapping, CommandForm form) throws FactoryException { //ERRO -> Não posso ter esses parâmetros

                Command command = CommandFactory.getInstance().getCommand(
                    commMapping.getCommandPath());
                CommandResponse commResponse = null;
                try {
                    commResponse = command.executeCommand(form, request, response, commMapping.isValidateForm());
                } catch (ServletException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                long tempFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long dif = (tempFinal - tempInicial);
                log.info("Requisição " + ": " + String.format("%02d segundos  e %02d milisegundos", dif/60, dif%60));

        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: É fácil passar parâmetros para uma Thread ou para um Runnable que você passa ao construtor da Thread. É só criar uma classe que implementa Runnable ou que estende Thread e passar os parâmetros no construtor. Agora quanto à sua estratégia de teste, não sei dizer se você está no caminho certo porque eu entendo que cada requisição já é tratada por uma thread separada no seu servlet container. E você está querendo passar os objetos request e response para novas threads em vez de medir o tempo do servlet... entendeu o que quero dizer? Mas não posso dar muito pitaco pq não entendi bem a intenção.

Comment: (e também porque não manjo muito de programação web heheh)

Comment: no caso eu quero simular como se estivessem ocorrendo 5 acessos ao serviço durante o mesmo período e quanto tempo levou cada uma dessas execuções, ja são requisições separadas devido ao servlet, porém não consigo fazer essa simulação de tempo simultânea

Comment: Entendi. O que você quer testar na verdade são as chamadas a executeCommand. Faça então como está na resposta do @Dudaskank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível passar parâmetros para o método `run()`, porém você pode criar uma classe que implemente `Runnable`, ou extenda `Thread`, e no construtor (ou via métodos get/set ou o que a criatividade permitir) passar os parâmetros que serão usados e guardar nos atributos da sua classe.

Outra coisa, a sua exceção `FactoryException` também não vai conseguir usar ela desse jeito. Você não pode alterar a assinatura do método, então terá que tratar ela dentro da thread.

No seu exemplo, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  HttpServletRequest request;
  HttpServletResponse response;
  String sequence;
  CommandMapping commMapping;
  CommandForm form;
  long tempInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();


  public MyRunnable(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String sequence, CommandMapping commMapping, CommandForm form) {
    this.request = request;
    this.response = response;
    this.sequence = sequence;
    this.commMapping = commMapping;
    this.form = form;
  }

  public void run() {
    // aqui pode usar normalmente os parâmetros agora
    try {
      Command command = CommandFactory.getInstance().getCommand(commMapping.getCommandPath());
      CommandResponse commResponse = null;
      try {
        commResponse = command.executeCommand(form, request, response, commMapping.isValidateForm());
      } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      long tempFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long dif = (tempFinal - tempInicial);
      log.info("Requisição " + ": " + String.format("%02d segundos  e %02d milisegundos", dif/60, dif%60));
    } catch(FactoryException fe) {
      fe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

E para criar e executar a thread:

```
Runnable r = new MyRunnable(request, response, sequence, commMapping, form);
new Thread(r).start();
```